# Python function keeps returning nan?

Tags: python, nan

I am currently learning python by rewriting some of the old programs I wrote using other languages. But for some reason, I keep running into an issue where a function call keeps returning a nan. Below is a code snippet.

The function theta0PartialDerivative returns a number if I call it outside the gradient descent function, but returns a nan otherwise. I am unsure what the issue is?

```
def theta0PartialDerivative():
    multBy=40.0
    total=temp=0

    for i in range(40):
        temp+=theta0
        temp+=theta1*sepalWidth[i]
        temp+=theta2*petalLength[i]
        temp+=theta3*petalWidth[i]
        temp-=sepalLength[i]
        total=total+temp
        temp=0
    return (multBy*total)

def gradientDescent():
    alpha=0.5
    global theta0,theta1,theta2,theta3
    theta0After=theta1After=theta2After=theta3After=1
    while(theta0After!=theta0 and theta1After!=theta1 and 
          theta2After!=theta2 and theta3After!=theta3):
        theta0=theta0After
        theta1=theta1After
        theta2=theta2After
        theta3=theta3After

        theta0After=theta0 - (alpha * theta0PartialDerivative())
        theta1After=theta1 - (alpha * theta1PartialDerivative())
        theta2After=theta2 - (alpha * theta2PartialDerivative())
        theta3After=theta3 - (alpha * theta3PartialDerivative())

theta0=theta1=theta2=theta3=accuracy=0
gradientDescent()
```

Full file here: https://github.com/MohamedMoustafaNUIG/Linear-Regression-Gradient-Descent-First-Project/blob/master/Linear-Regression-I.py

EDIT: Really? No one knows what the issue is?

Comment: Can you show how you call it inside the `gradientDescent()` function?
Can you attach illustrated results for both function calls ? 
Share more of the code because what is here doesn't seem to be enough

Comment: I did show how it is called "theta0After=theta0 - (alpha * theta0PartialDerivative())". If I write print(theta0PartialDerivative()) inside the function it prints nan, outside it prints -8059.999999999999. What more code do you want?sepal/petal length/width are all int lists. I am reading a txt file with 50 records and using 40 of them to train a function to predict the sepal length using the other 3 attributes.

Comment: @DavidSidarous here is a repo with the python file: https://github.com/MohamedMoustafaNUIG/Linear-Regression-Gradient-Descent-First-Project/blob/master/Linear-Regression-I.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Alpha, the step variable, was too large (for the dataset I was dealing with) and caused the partial derivatives to diverge instead of converge. I changed alpha from 0.5 to 0.13 and it works